# Reasoning for using Pub/Sub vs Service

Tags: ros, action, ros-service, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm struggling to determine when I should use the various communication methods ROS offers, like the publish/subscriber model, service, or action.

I figure, sensors should be publishers, short running processes can be services, and longer running ones should be actions. Do those make sense? Are there other rules of thumb to follow?

For example, I was looking at the rosserial tutorial for controlling a servo motor, and saw it was using a subscriber to move. I would have chosen a service. What would be the reasoning for choosing one over the other?

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251580/reasoning-for-using-pub/sub-vs-service/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question explains the reasoning and scenarios for each pretty well: http://answers.ros.org/question/11834/when-should-i-use-topics-vs-services-vs-actionlib-actions-vs-dynamic_reconfigure/

This is also documented on the [ROS Communication Patterns page](http://answers.ros.org/question/11834/when-should-i-use-topics-vs-services-vs-actionlib-actions-vs-dynamic_reconfigure/) that is linked from that question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on 2017-01-15**:
so for the example of controlling a servo motor, it should be a topic if its continuously updating its position, a service if its a quick movement with discrete move requests, and an action if its slow?